# What Emotion Do You Experience When You Feel "Honored"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

There are a ton of situations where it would be appropriate to start a sentence with the phrase "I'm honored."  For example, "I'm honored to receive this award."  "I'm honored to be a guest at your wedding." Etc.

However, try as I might, I can't put my finger on what emotion the person who feels honored is actually feeling.  Is there a better way to refer to this feeling other than "feeling honored?"

Comment: It  very much depends on personal feelings and opinions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about psychology.

Answer (score 2):

**Honor** is the emotion itself.

*In-Mind Magazine*

> Imagine as a 7-year-old not knowing the meaning of the word shame. This would seem rather improbable to you if you were raised in a culture that values honor. Growing up, you most likely heard some variation of the word every day from parents, teachers, or siblings. However, this familiarity with shame does not extend to all cultures. For example, research has shown that Dutch children seem to learn about the emotion much later than Spanish children.